# How do I remove the aerator on a Kohler Artifacts faucet

Tags: plumbing

I have a Kohler [k-72760-4](https://s1.img-b.com/build.com/mediabase/specifications/kohler/936283/kohler-k-72760-4-specsheet-9.pdf), and I can't figure out how to remove the aerator.  It looks like an inside male threaded aerator and I tried buying a key to unscrew but it looks like I bought one that was too big, and even still I don't see the slots where a smaller key would fit.

What key do I need to remove, and can I remove without a key using a screwdriver or some other tool?

[image]

Comment: Could you take a close-up of the relevant bit? What you have is no use.

Comment: Added link to photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does not look like the sort of aerator that uses a key to remove.

The only way I know to remove them is grip them snugly either with channel-locks and a washcloth between the plier jaws and the aerator (so as not to mar the finish) or a rubber strap wrench and unscrewing the aerator counterclockwise.

Comment: Which part would I grip?  The aerator is inside the faucet so I don't know what I'd be able to get a grip on.  Are you saying I should try to slip in between the aerator and the inside faucet wall?

Comment: Oh I see, the whole housing comes off with enough force if I twist around the outside of the entire tip.